# Скрипт периода (времени года) - PHP, что я делаю не так?

Tags: php

Хочу больше интерактивности на свой проектик.
Добавил это:

```
function season()
{

$season;

$curdate = date("d.m.Y", strtotime("now"));

$summer_start = "01.06.".date("Y"); // 01 июня текущего года
$summer_end = "31.08.".date("Y"); // 31 августа текущего года

$spring_start = "01.03.".date("Y"); // 01 марта текущего года
$spring_end = "31.05.".date("Y"); // 31 мая текущего года

$autumn_start = "01.09.".date("Y"); // 01 сентября текущего года
$autumn_end = "30.11.".date("Y"); // 30 ноября текущего года

$winter_start = "01.12.".date("Y"); // 01 декабря текущего года
$winter_end = "28.02.".date("Y"); // 28 февраля текущего года

if (strtotime($curdate) < strtotime($winter_start) and strtotime($curdate) >  strtotime($winter_end))

    {
        $season = $season;
    }
else
    {
        $season = "- зима! Низкие температуры! Низкие цены!";
    }

if (strtotime($curdate) > strtotime($spring_start) and strtotime($curdate) <  strtotime($spring_end))

    {
        $season = "весна - цены тают!";
    }
else
    {
        $season = $season;
    }


if (strtotime($curdate) > strtotime($summer_start) and strtotime($curdate) <  strtotime($summer_end))

    {
        $season = "лето - цены прячутся в тень!";
    }
else
    {
        $season = $season;
    }

if (strtotime($curdate) > strtotime($autumn_start) and strtotime($curdate) <  strtotime($autumn_end))
    {
        $season = "осень и у нас осенний ценопад!";
    }
else
    {
        $season = $season;
    }

print "<b>".$season."</b>";
}
```

Но оно ничего не выводит. Вывод делаю `season()`. Что в коде не так?

Comment: Может вы еще расскажете что хотелось бы выводить?

Comment: to: u-mulder А из текста после кода это разве не понятно?

Comment: А зачем вы вообще проверяете день и год? Может достаточно проверить месяц или не, это слишком просто?

Comment: Ну... тут вы правы (на счёт месяца), просто движок скрипта брас со старого прожекта, там ловлю дату Дня победы и НГ.--- А код исправил. Подставил <= и >= всё заработало. Указывал просто первое число, вот и не показывало.
Попробую сейчас даты откинуть - спасибо за идею!

Comment: `$season = $season;` это простите что вообще такое?

Comment: @metalurgus: видимо, паттерн проектирования )

Answer (score 2):

я чутка его упростил, он, вроде, заработал. Думаю, вы запутались в условиях ифов

```
$curdate = date("d.m.Y", time());

$summer_start = "01.06.".date("Y"); // 01 июня текущего года
$summer_end = "31.08.".date("Y"); // 31 августа текущего года

$spring_start = "01.03.".date("Y"); // 01 марта текущего года
$spring_end = "31.05.".date("Y"); // 31 мая текущего года

$autumn_start = "01.09.".date("Y"); // 01 сентября текущего года
$autumn_end = "30.11.".date("Y"); // 30 ноября текущего года

$winter_start = "01.12.".date("Y"); // 01 декабря текущего года
$winter_end = "28.02.".date("Y"); // 28 февраля текущего года

if (strtotime($curdate) >= strtotime($winter_start) and strtotime($curdate) <=  strtotime($winter_end))
    {
        $season = "- зима! Низкие температуры! Низкие цены!";
    }

if (strtotime($curdate) >= strtotime($spring_start) and strtotime($curdate) <=  strtotime($spring_end))

    {
        $season = "весна - цены тают!";
    }

if (strtotime($curdate) >= strtotime($summer_start) and strtotime($curdate) <=  strtotime($summer_end))
    {
        $season = "лето - цены прячутся в тень!";
    }

if (strtotime($curdate) >= strtotime($autumn_start) and strtotime($curdate) <=  strtotime($autumn_end))
    {
        $season = "осень и у нас осенний ценопад!";
    }
echo $season ;
```

Comment: C Зимой запутался!!!  
Там период (НГ - переход года меня с мыслей сбил)

Comment: НЕТ!!!! Зима по прежнему не работает!
В ней ведь переход года.

Comment: ушел от компа :( ставьте везде elseif, зиму оставьте последней - что останется :)

Comment: Всё заработало с моим кодом!  
Просто не указал "<=" и ">="  
И ставил 1 число когда проверял, поэтому-то и не выводило!  
Спасибо!  
Ваш ответ дал толчок к повторному копанию в коде и ошибка(недочёт) был найден!

Comment: В високосный год удивитесь..

Comment: Всё заработало с моим кодом! Просто не указал "<=" и ">=" И ставил 1 число когда проверял, поэтому-то и не выводило! Спасибо! Ответ splash58 - дал толчок к повторному копанию и ошибка(недочёт) был найден!

Comment: 29-го в моём коде ни чего не отобразится просто!
Проверил! Один день раз в 4 года, люди обойдутся без скидок ;)

Comment: Простой выход из ситуации с 29-ым февраля:
[code]if (strtotime($curdate) <= strtotime($winter_start) and strtotime($curdate) >=  strtotime($winter_end))
    {
        $season = "29 февраля";
    }
else
    {
       $season = "- зима! Низкие температуры! Низкие цены!";  
    }[/code]

Answer (score 2):

При желании весь скрипт можно упростить:

```
$result = floor(date('n') / 3);
if ($result == 1) {
    // это весна
} elseif ($result == 2) {
    // это лето
} elseif ($result == 3) {
    // это осень
} else {
    // это зима
}
```

Comment: Люблю свой код, так как каждую заковырку знаю. А тут как-то разбираться надо.
Вот тут как-то понятнее и тоже коротко:
http://rotorweb.ru/dizajn/smena-dizajna-po-vremenam-goda.html

Answer (score 0):

просто в первом коде надо было все таки функцию season() в конце вызвать. И $season = $season в else лишнее.